# React how to manage same multiple child components state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have implemented the following example, where I am keeping all child state info in the parent component in the form of array.

```
const parent= (props) => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
   
   const data = new Array(num).fill().map((_,i) => { id: i, name: ''});
   setData(data);

   /* 
     if num=5; then data becomes,

     data=[{id: 0, name: ''},{id: 1, name: ''},{id: 2, name: ''},{id: 3, name: ''},{id: 4, name: ''}]; 

 */

  ),[num]}

  const changeVal = (val, id) => {
    const newData = data.map(d => d.id === id ? {...d, name: val} : d)
    setData(newData);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      
      {
        data.map(val => {
         return (
           <Child val={val} changeVal={changeVal}/>
         )
      })
      }

     <button onClick={() => alert(data)}>Show All State</button>
    </div>
  )
}



// Child Component
const Child = (props) => {
   const { val, changeVal } = props;
   
   return(
    <input type="text" value={val} onChange={(e) => changeVal(e.target.value, val.id)} />
  );
}
```

Also, I want to show all child components state information when clicked on the button in the parent component.

num - denotes the number of child components, it can change dynamically.

so, my question is that, is this a better approach to handle the state of multiple child components. ?

is there any better and efficient solution than the above one without using Redux. ?

Are there any problems in using the above approach. ?

Comment: Why don't you keep the state in the child component?

Comment: there is no relation of redux here.

Comment: @YohaiM if I do it how can I get all child components state on button click. ? let's suppose in parent component I have a button, if I clicked it, it should retrieve state from all child component. how can I implement it?

Comment: @MR.Kumar I don't want to use Redux here.

Comment: You can make the child receive an onValue prop which is a callback, and then the parent can pass <Child  onValue={(value) => doSomething(value)}/>

Comment: @YohaiM do you mean in - doSomething(value), I should create array in parent component and push the state changes into that array. so when I click on button in parent component will show all child component state. ? is this the right way ?.

Comment: @YohaiM I have edited the question, see if I use state inside child component, how can show all child component state when clicked on the button in parent. ?